# d3.js controling two graphs with same select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, graph, d3.js

So I have need to put two d3js graphs in same website and I wanna control them with same select element.

Firstly when I managed to get working first graph in a way I wanna, I've just copied the script for second graph but in different container. Result was awful. Graphs were clashing because variables were named in the same way.

Later I distinguished all vairables from first graph with adding `_1` on the end of each variable name and for second adding `_2` on the end of variable names.

Now Graphs are displaying correctly. But the problem I have is with my change function which is called on change of select option. When you have one select box for every graph, Everything works great, but when I tried to set this up so one select box controls both graphs I had bad time.

**The code is really long so in further I will put here only part of codes for which I'm talking about. the whole code and exapmle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/g3MHp/**

*(p.s. the script for first graph is in html, I know it is not wright approach for jsfiddle but I wanna reflect the true state, as in original document)*

So, for the first example I have to register change of select box:

```
d3.selectAll(".graph_change_1").on("change", change_1);
```

and then call `change_1` function:

```
function change_1() {

            graph_n_1 = this.value;

            //remove guides
            d3.selectAll(".guide_1").transition().duration(100).styleTween("opacity", 
                        function() { return d3.interpolate(.5, 0); })
            .remove()

            if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){
                x_1.domain([0, dataX_1[0].cn_bpr_to]);
                y_1.domain([0, dataY_1[0].bpr_to]);
            }
            if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){
                x_1.domain([0, dataX_1[0].cn_pr_to]);
                y_1.domain([0, dataY_1[0].pr_to]);
            }
            if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){
                x_1.domain([0, dataX_1[0].cn_as_to]);
                y_1.domain([0, dataY_1[0].as_to]);
            }

            // First transition the line & label to the new city.
            var t0_1 = svg_1.transition().duration(750);
            t0_1.selectAll(".line_1").attr("d", line_1);

            // Then transition the y-axis.
            yAxisRF_1 = yAxis_1.tickFormat( function(n){
                                            if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return n; }
                                            if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return n; }
                                            if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){

                                                var nLen_1 = n.toString().length;

                                                if(nLen_1> 12){
                                                    nLenS_1 = n/Math.pow(10,12);
                                                    addS_1 = "Bil.€";
                                                }else if(nLen_1 > 9){
                                                    nLenS_1 = n/Math.pow(10,9);
                                                    addS_1 = "Md.€";
                                                }else if(nLen_1 > 6){
                                                    nLenS_1 = n/Math.pow(10,6);
                                                    addS_1 = "Mio.€";
                                                }else if(nLen_1 > 3){
                                                    nLenS_1 = n/Math.pow(10,3);
                                                    addS_1 = "T€";
                                                }else{
                                                        nLenS_1 = 0/Math.pow(10,0);
                                                        addS_1 = "€";
                                                }



                                                var podlj_1 = nLen_1/3;
                                                var podljR_1 = Math.round(podlj_1)

                                                if (podlj_1 == podljR_1){
                                                    x2_1=0   
                                                }else{ x2_1=1 }

                                                var Fn_1 = nLenS_1.toFixed(x2);

                                                var FnR_1 = Fn_1.toString().replace(".0","").replace(".",",");

                                                var FaddT_1 = addS_1;

                                                return FnR_1+" "+FaddT_1;

                                            }
                                       });

            xAxisRF_1 = xAxis_1.tickValues(x_1.domain())

            var t1_1 = t0_1.transition();

            t1_1.selectAll(".desc_val_1").text( function(){
                                        if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return "Business Page Rank (BPR)"; }
                                        if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return "Page Rank (PR)"; }
                                        if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return "Euro (€)"; }
                                   })

            t1_1.selectAll(".line_1").attr("d", line_1);
            t1_1.selectAll(".y.axis_1").call(yAxisRF_1);
            t1_1.selectAll(".x.axis_1").call(xAxisRF_1);

            line_1.interpolate("basis")
            .x(function(d) {
                            if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return x_1(d.cn_bpr); }
                            if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return x_1(d.cn_pr); }
                            if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return x_1(d.cn_as); }
                        })
            .y(function(d) { return y_1(d[graph_n_1]); });


        svg_1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "guide_1")
            .data(dataC_1)
        .append("line")
            .attr("x1", function(d) {   
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +x_1(d.x3); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +x_1(d.x2); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +x_1(d.x1); } 
                                })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {   
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +x_1(d.x3); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +x_1(d.x2); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +x_1(d.x1); } 
                                })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { 
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +y_1(d.y3)+4; }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +y_1(d.y2)+4; }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +y_1(d.y1)+4; } 
                                })
            .attr("y2", height_1)
            .style("stroke",  "#c45c28")
            .transition().delay(500).duration(400).styleTween("opacity", 
                        function() { return d3.interpolate(0, .5); })

        svg_1.append("g")
            .attr("class", "guide_1")
            .data(dataC_1)
        .append("line")
            .attr("x1", function(d) {   
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +x_1(d.x3-5); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +x_1(d.x2-5); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +x_1(d.x1-5); } 
                                })
            .attr("x2", 0)
            .attr("y1", function(d) { 
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +y_1(d.y3); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +y_1(d.y2); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +y_1(d.y1); } 
                                })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { 
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +y_1(d.y3); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +y_1(d.y2); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +y_1(d.y1); } 
                                })
            .style("stroke", "#c45c28")
            .transition().delay(500).duration(400).styleTween("opacity", 
                        function() { return d3.interpolate(0, .5); });

         t1_1.selectAll(".circles_1").attr({
                cx: function(d) {   
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +x_1(d.x3); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +x_1(d.x2); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +x_1(d.x1); } 
                                },
                cy: function(d) { 
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "BPR"){ return +y_1(d.y3); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "PR"){ return +y_1(d.y2); }
                                    if(graph_n_1 == "assets"){ return +y_1(d.y1); } 
                                },
                r: 4,
                id: function(d) { return d.company; }
              })

        }
```

When I added same function under the same name in **second grap**h, The change of select box ignored the `first graph` and changed only **second graph**

So ok, it is because functions have same name, I've changed function name and then only was selecting same select box, but the result is the same as previous try.

Then I added a second select box and tried to control this second with change of first one with jQuery. On select of first, value changed on second but second graph remained same.

It's obivous, on inserting of value there is no change event.

So currently I'm out of idea. What I need to change to get control of two graphs with just one selectbox?

You can check my situation and edit in as linked above: http://jsfiddle.net/g3MHp/

Any help or suggestion is welcome..

Comment: You would need a single `change` function that is called from the select box which changes both graphs. That is, take the code from both `change_1` and `change_2` and put it into one function.

Comment: I've did just like that and it works like charm... Even I did it before your suggestion, please put the answer for points :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a single `change` function that is called from the select box which changes both graphs. That is, take the code from both `change_1` and `change_2` and put it into one function.